# Variable of elementFromPoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch-event

Firstly, I got a `div` selected by touchstart, with the instruction:

```
var firstSelectedItem = $(this);
```

Then I retrieve a new `div` element with `touchmove` according to the coordinates of the mouse:

```
e.preventDefault ();
var touch = e.originalEvent.touches [0] || e.originalEvent.changedTouches [0];
var x = touch.pageX;
var y = touch.pageY;
var currentElement = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
```

Except that the `currentElement` is not an object. How to render it in object exactly like `$this`?

Thank you for your support.

Comment: Your question isn't clear

Comment: If the speciefied point is out of the document's visible part, eFP returns `null`.

Comment: I want to make a swapping between two div by sending to my function $(this) and currentElement. But, my function need 2 variables with the same form : the form of $(this) is needed.

So, how to convert currentElement like $(this) before send to my swapping function?

Thank a lot.

Comment: For example, when I write the following instruction : $(this).attr('id'), I have a value, but went I use the same to currentElement like currentElement.attr('id'), it's appear an error.yet currentElement has a value that elementFromPoint gave him. How to solve it?